# Ip blocked since I updated my Mac to Mountain Lion

Tags: macos, osx-lion, firewall, osx-mountain-lion

Since I've upgraded my mac from lion to mountain lion, the ip 5.9.31.48 (api.shellycloud.com) appear to be down (ping said that "Host is down"). So I think that there is somewhere a firewall rule that block all request from this ip or hostname.

I use Little snwitch, so to be sure I've clossed it, same for the mountain lion build-in firewall. But nothing change, still down.
I've checked my /etc/hosts to.

Does someone have any idea ?

Comment: Is there a _programming_ question here? If not, you should ask this on [Ask Different](http://askdifferent.com)

Comment: No, it's a programming question. I didn't know that stackoverflow was only for programming question. Thanks for the other web site.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the Hamachi VPN client installed on your Mac? It reserves the 5.x.x.x IP addresses for communicating with other Hamachi hosts, meaning that your computer can't talk to anything that has a real address starting with 5. See [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamachi_%28software%29#Addressing) for more detail.

Comment: Amazing, thank you Gordon Davisson ! I've removed Hamachi and that work now.